# TCP SYN request failing in gingerbread

Tags: android, http, tcp

I have a server programmm running on android 2.2 and client running on a LInux desktop.Everything was working fine .When I moved my application to gingerbread code base whenever the linux application send an HTTP request to my android server application immediately after SYN request android app is sending a RST .Why is it so any idea?
Do we need to change anything when mobving to ginger bread ?
Regards
Kozlov

Answer (score 0):

A RST in response to a SYN means that the port is not open.  You need to check your Android app to make sure it's opening the port number you think it is and that the open was successful.

It's *possible* that some firewall rules are causing this but unlikely since firewall filtering usually generates no response at all.